# Источник бесконечного ресурса (еды/богатства)

Tags: фольклор, сравнение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в сказках или мифах (не обязательно русских) какая-то сущность — источник бесконечного ресурса: сколько из него ни возьми, количество не уменьшается.
Мне на ум пришли пока только **неразменный рубль**, **скатерть-самобранка** и **рог изобилия**. Но, возможно, найдется что-то более подходящее под описание?

Comment: На ответ не тянет, но вот вспомнилось ещё: "серебряное копытце", "золотая антилопа".

Comment: Да, я думал об антилопе тоже. Но это немного не то, как мне кажется. В общем, мне нужен хороший аналог "копирования" из мира мифов - взял что-то, в итоге у тебя что-то есть и у источника не уменьшилось. Эдакий непересыхающий родник.

Comment: Волшебный горшочек ("Сладкая каша" братьев Гримм)

Comment: Уточнили бы, чем именно ваши примеры "не такие". Тут ведь какое-то философское противоречие. С одной стороны, понятно, что эти примеры **возобновляемого** ресурса, а вовсе не **бесконечного**. А с другой - а как иначе можно представить подобную бесконечность? Как море (в понимании древних)? Или колодец? Сколько ни черпай - меньше не становится? Так не бывает. Если это ресурс, то при его использовании, его должно становиться меньше.  И только потом уже ресурс как-то возобновляется... Иначе он перестает быть ресурсом - и следовательно предметом фольклора.

Answer (score 1):

Я вынес сюда свой комментарий, он явно выходит за пределы простой реплики.

Уточнили бы, чем именно ваши примеры "не такие". Тут ведь какое-то философское противоречие. С одной стороны, понятно, что эти примеры **возобновляемого** ресурса, а вовсе не **бесконечного**. А с другой - а как иначе можно представить подобную бесконечность? Как море (в понимании древних)? Или колодец? Сколько ни черпай - меньше не становится? Так не бывает. Если это ресурс, то при его использовании, его должно становиться меньше.  И только потом уже ресурс как-то возобновляется... Иначе он перестает быть ресурсом - и следовательно предметом фольклора.

Если я правильно понял требования к такому источнику, то можно вспомнить только "рог изобилия". 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B3_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F

Его принципиальное отличие от всего названного в том, что он всегда "полон" - и при этом имеет некий конечный объем. Но даже в этом случае он с большой натяжкой подходит под определение "ресурса". Бесконечный ресурс перестает быть ресурсом, поскольку перестает в чем-то ограничивать потребителя... Ну как воздух. В каком фольклоре можно представить упоминание о сказочном источнике обычного воздуха, если он есть в реальности?!

Есть еще Сампо - сказочная ручная мельница из "Калевалы". Но она еще ближе к скатерти-самобранке, отличается только непрерывностью действия.

Ну и конечно аналоги всех эти "горшочки каши" во всех видах присутствуют, наверное, у всех народов... Но это уже совсем не то, если смотреть на принцип действия. Они варят кашу не потому, что кто-то что-то взял из них, а независимо от факта потребления (На чем сказка бр. Гримм и построена).

Comment: Самым близким, как мне кажется, является неразменный рубль (или неразменный пятак, в некоторых вариантах). Встречал интерпретации, где если нужно заплатить, скажем, 100 рублей, то нужно 100 раз опустить руку в карман и достать оттуда этот рубль. А в кармане рубль снова появляется. Я себе подобную конструкцию представляю, например как полная чаша, из которой, если нам нужно испить или наполнить другую чашу - мы наклоняем "бесконечную чашу" и жидкость льется и наполняет нашу, когда мы возвращаем "волшебную" чашу в ровное положение - уровень жидкости в ней на том же уровне, как и был.

Comment: @Michel_T.- тогда не вижу причин для *найдется что-то более подходящее под описание*. При такой трактовке **все** подходит. (Кроме слова "ресурс", ну это ладно").

Answer (score 0):

кладезь, сокровищница, неиссякаемый родник